# Array as Volley POST request params

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-volley

I am trying to make a volley POST request with a array as my parameter, for example I want to POST

```
{"types":[1,2,3]}
```

what I have now is a string

```
{"types":"[1,2,3]"}
```

This is how I made my volley request:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    try{
        jsonObject.put("types", list);
        jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
        System.out.println(jsonObject);
    }catch(Exception e){

    }

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    Log.e("Response", response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e("Error.Response", error.toString());
                    String json = null;
                    NetworkResponse response = error.networkResponse;
                    if(response != null && response.data != null){
                        switch(response.statusCode){
                            case 400:

                                json = new String(response.data);
                                System.out.println(json);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Authorization", Token);
            return headers;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

List is an array list declared as:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

I am assuming that jsonObject.put("types", list) will turn my array into a list, how should I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to create a `JSONArray` from your list of integers and add that to `jsonObject`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `List`, try `JSONArray`.

```
JSONArray types=new JSONArray();
types.put(1);
types.put(2);
types.put(3);
jsonObject.put("types", types);
jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
```

This should fix your issue

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, that was exactly the problem thank you!

Comment: @JerryKo i need help

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan How can I help you?