# How To POST Array With Volley Method in Android, Here Last index value is posting in Database

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-volley

This is Volley function. I used array and there are multiple values like arra[]={1,2,4,5} i want send this array with parameter.put("Data", array[]) how this will be happend?

```
public void sendData(){
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, insertUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                System.out.println(response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                Map<String,String> parameters  = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    for(int i =0;i<array.length;i++) {
                        String A= array[i].toString();
                        parameters.put("Generated",A);
                    }

                return parameters;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }
```

Comment: You should and it's better to use JSONArray and JsonObjectRequest, look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870263

Answer (score 0):

You may need to convert from gson to json.

Add your library.

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'
```

And then

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").create();

parameters.put("Generated",gson.toJson(array));
```